# Objective C style nil in java?

Tags: java, objective-c

Objective C has a concept of a nil object which would accept any method call with any parameters without complaining and silently return another nil.

I have used something similar in Java using easymock and mockito for testing. Is there something similar for main line code? Is it even a good idea to have something like this?

One use-case where I am considering using it is with optional metrics. We have codahale metrics counters on which we call mark() every time an event is generated. This is surrounded by an If/then to check for metrics enabled flag. I could just use a nil object as counter and silently accept the mark call if metrics are not enabled.

Comment: how do you handle methods with primitive result type? (eg. equals and hashCode)

Comment: Bear in mind that `nil` is not an object -- it's a pointer that doesn't point to anything. The language happens to be defined such that it's (often) legal to send messages to `nil`, but `nil` doesn't represent an object. (Of course, there's also `[NSNull null]`, which *is* an object.)

Comment: @user470365: In such cases, the equivalent of "0" for that primitive type is returned (i.e., "NO", "0", "0.0", etc.).

Comment: @Caleb it's _always_, not _often_, legal to message `nil`. Some other objects don't like having `nil` as a message parameter.

Comment: @GrahamLee Perhaps I was being too careful. *Sending* a message to `nil` is always legal, using the returned value may not be, so while *legal* it may nevertheless be an error. As you point out, some methods may not like `nil` as a parameter. E.g. `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[foo name]]` will throw an exception if foo is `nil` because `[foo name]` will return nil. Sending `-name` to `foo` is legal, but that's not much comfort to the user who wonders why your app just crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have this built in - it's a programmer error to call a message on `null` which causes a runtime exception. However, there *is* a pattern called the [Null Object Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/null-object-pattern.html), which programmers use to provide their own equivalent.

Imagine that you have some interface, representing a connection to a database. You might define the interface like this:

```
public interface DatabaseConnection {
public void connect(String username, String password, URL databaseLocation);
public void disconnect();
public String executeQuery(String query);
}
```

Your Null Object might look like this:

```
public class NullDatabaseConnection implements DatabaseConnection {
public void connect(String username, String password, URL databaseLocation) {}
public void disconnect() {}
public String executeQuery(String query) { return ""; }
}
```

The disadvantage of doing this compared with the ObjC approach is that you have to write the above code - you can't automatically get the behaviour by using the `nil` object. The advantage is that this explicit Null object works as you'd expect in all cases: you can put it into a collection for example, something you can't do with Objective-C's `nil`.

Comment: Hmm this will work, I can probably create a utility class which takes an interface and returns an implementation which mocks out all the methods according some basic rules, nulls for objects default values for primitives. I mostly want to use it for void methods anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental part of the [Objective-C runtime](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/runtime/Messengers.subproj/objc-msg-arm.s). On *every single method call*, the first thing it does is check if the object reference is `nil`, and immediately returns if so. The Java runtime surely does a similar check, but responds by throwing a NullPointerException. So you're asking how to change the fundamental behaviour of the runtime.

There are a couple of ways to achieve a similar effect in Java:

- Create a dummy implementation of your metrics interface that does nothing. Assign this to your metrics object variable.
- or: Create a single, static entry point to your metrics class, and pass in the instance as the first argument, and check if it's null before doing anything else. e.g.

.

```
public static void doMetrics(Metrics m, otherArgs ...) {
    if (m == null) return;

    ... do stuff with m ...
}
```

Both of these come at the minor performance cost of a pointless method call when metrics are switched off.